# How to prevent git from packing object files?

Tags: git

I'm using a single object directory to hold the blobs from all git repositories on my machine by using this environment variable:

```
export GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY="$HOME/.local/share/git/objects"
```

I would like each blob to be its own file, but git automatically packs them into packfiles.

Having each file's name be its hash and the contents be the contents of the blob would help me with the goal of serving the files over IPFS. (Otherwise, they wouldn't have the right hash and would be hard to find on the DHT.)

It seems like they are called "loose objects" when in this expanded state, but I couldn't find how to make that the default storage method. Is there a setting or workaround for this?

Comment: This is an interesting concept, but I'm curious about garbage collection. In Git, objects can easily become unreferenced (e.g. when deleting a branch, amending, debasing, etc.) How can git safely perform garbage collection if it can "see" objects that belong to another repository? It seems like gc would have to be disabled completely if `GIT_OBJECT_DIRECTORY` is used.

Comment: Yeah I thought about the same thing, wrote it on a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788715/how-does-git-know-which-files-not-to-prune-when-using-a-common-git-object-direct